# Simulate long exposure from video frames OpenCV

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, opencv

I am trying to simulate a long exposure photo by combining images(frames) into one image and by performing operations based on a preset alpha. I am doing this on an iPhone, and I currently have the length of the video set to 1 second(30 frames). The alpha is set to `1.0/frameCount` however I hard coded in 30 to represent one second of 30 FPS video capture. I stop the operations once it has reached one second of video/30 frames. The idea is the user can set a timer for x seconds and I will do the math to figure out how many frames to allow.

Here is the code I am using:

```
- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image
{

    if (_isRecording) {

        // first frame
        
        double alpha = 1.0/30;
        
        if (_frameCount == 0) {
            
            _exposed = image;
            _frameCount++;
        } else {
            
            Mat exposed = _exposed.clone();
            addWeighted(exposed, alpha, image, 1.0 - alpha, 0.0, _exposed);
            _frameCount++;
        }

        // stop and save image
        if (_frameCount == 30) {
            _isRecording = NO;
            _frameCount = 0;
            
            cvtColor(_exposed, _exposed, CV_BGRA2RGB, 30);
            UIImage *exposed = [LEMatConverter UIImageFromCVMat:_exposed];
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(exposed, nil, nil, nil);
            NSLog(@"saved");
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code I basically get back a still image that looks as if it is a single frame. Here is an example:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can produce the desired effect of a long exposure image from video frames given I know how many frames there will be?

Comment: problem in your code is that you are doing averaging of only 1 frames 30 times.

Answer (score 14):

First of all, (probably this is not your case, as you pointed out that you are working on a video and not a camera) if you base your code on the value of the frame rate, be sure that 30fps is the effective value and not the maximum one. Sometimes cameras automatically adjust that number based on the amount of light they get from the environment. If it is dark, then the exposure time is increased and therefore the framerate is diminished.

Second point, it is really hard to simulate the real mechanism of photo exposure given a bunch of pixels.
Imagine you want to double the exposure time, this should be simulated by two consecutive frames.
In the real world doubling the exposure time means that the shutter speed is halved and so twice as much light hits the sensor or film, the result is a brighter image.
How do you simulate this? Consider for simplicity the case of two quite bright grayscale images you want to merge. If in a given point the pixel values are, say, 180 and 181 what is the resulting value? The first answer would be 180+181, but pixel intensities ranges between 0 and 255, so it has to be truncated at 255.
The real camera with increased exposure probably would behave differently, not reaching the maximum value.

Now I’ll consider you code.
The first time you process an image (i.e. run the function), you simply store the frame in variable _exposed.
The second time you blend 29/30 of the new frame and 1/30 of the previously stored image.
The third time 29/30 of the third frame with the result of previous operation. This results in placing a fading weight on the first frame which is virtually disappeared.
The last time you call the function, again, you sum up 29/30 of the last frame and 1/30 of the previous result. In turn this means that the effect of the first frames is virtually disappeared and even the previous one counts only for a share of 29/(30x30).
The image you get is just the last frame with a slight blur coming from the previous frames.
How do you obtain a simulation of exposure?
If you simply want to average 30 frames you have to replace these lines:

```
    if (_frameCount == 0) {
       _exposed = image.clone();
        addWeighted(_exposed, 0.0, image, alpha, 0.0, _exposed);
    } else {
        addWeighted(_exposed, 1.0, image, alpha, 0.0, _exposed);
    }
    _frameCount++;
```

If you also want to make the image brighter to some extent, you could simulate it via a multiplication factor:

```
    if (_frameCount == 0) {
       _exposed = image.clone();
        addWeighted(_exposed, 0.0, image, alpha*brightfactor, 0.0, _exposed);
    } else {
        addWeighted(_exposed, 1.0, image, alpha*brightfactor, 0.0, _exposed);
    }
    _frameCount++;
```

Tune brightfactor to a value it best simulate a real increasing in exposure time. (EDIT: a value between 1.5 and 2.5 should do the job)

Comment: Great, I saw this function in the docs but hadn't given it a shot, I'll try it out. Thanks for the extra insight as well.

Comment: I have a question with your answer, why is the alpha in the first line zero? Won't this make the `src1` image completely clear? Same question with the beta of the second call. Thanks! Also I Just tried it out and it seems to work fairly well, do you know of anyway I could make the image slightly clearer/lower the sensitivity between frames?

Comment: The alpha equal zero in the first line is just a trick to use a code similar to the one of the second line. It takes the first frame and multiplies it for 1/30, that makes it much darker (_exposed is not summed up now). Then the second line adds this dark image to 1/30 of the current frame. Every time it is executed the resulting image (_exposed) becomes clearer. The effect is an averaging of 30 frames, just like the one obtained from a long exposure.

Comment: But the effect of a real increased exposure is also a brighter image: you can simulate it via the brightfactor parameter. Vary its values to find out the one which best simulates a real long exposure. Start with a value of 1.5 and increase it.

Comment: I tried it out but I did not see any difference in exposed and original imager.

Comment: Replying to old post but maybe relevant for some people today such as moi who who had the same idea to video comet neowise on a phone and use the video to simulate long exposure.  I have implemented above and will add that i ensured the image mat are floats so that the accumulated values are not rounded until the final conversion.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion using alpha is not the correct way.

You should accumulate the (absolute) differences from the exposure frame:

```
if (_frameCount == 0) {
   _exposed = image.clone();
} else {
   _exposed += image - _exposed;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't simulate well the simple situation of a still image.  In a real camera the resulting image is bright, in your code you'll get the original frame.

Comment: it's also do not simulate the blur effect, the question is how far Nick wants the exposed effect to be close to reality

Answer (score 1):

Following approach should work in a case where

- you have a known (or learned) background
- you can segment the motion so that you get a mask for the foreground

Suppose you obtained such a background and can get a foreground mask for each frame that you capture after the background-learning stage. Let's denote

- the learned background as ***bg***
- frame at time ***t*** as ***I_t***
- corresponding foreground mask for *I_t* as ***fgmask_t***

Then update the background for each frame as

***I_t.copyTo(bg, fgmask_t)***

where ***copyTo*** is a method of OpenCV Mat class.

So the procedure would be

```
Learn bg

for each frame I_t
{
    get fgmask_t
    I_t.copyTo(bg, fgmask_t)
}
```

When frame capture is over, ***bg*** will contain the history of motion.

You can use a Gaussian Mixture Model (*BackgroundSubtractorMOG* variants in OpenCV) or a simple frame differencing technique for this. The quality will depend on how well the technique segments the motion (or the quality of the foreground mask).

I think this should work well for a stationary camera, but if the camera moves, it may not work very well except in a situation where the camera tracks an object.